# Push from one sql server to another autonomously

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, database-connection

I have an application that requires me to pull certain information from DB#1 and push it to DB#2 every time a certain entry in a table from DB#1 is updated. The polling rate doesn't need to be extremely fast, but it probably shouldn't be any slower than 1 second.
I was planning on writing a small service using the C++ Connector library, but I am worried about putting too much load on DB#1. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Such as built in functionality within an SQL script?

Comment: Have you looked at replication, this looks like what you need.  An example of setting one up http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2010/transactional-replication-2008-r2/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many methods to accomplish this, so it may be other factors you prefer that drive the approach.

If the SQL Server databases are on the same server instance:

- Trigger on the DB1 tables that push to the DB2 tables
- Stored procedure (in DB1 or DB2) that uses `MERGE` to identify changes and sync them to DB2, then use SQL job to call the procedure on your schedule
- Enable Change Tracking on database and desired tables, then use stored proc + SQL job to send changes without any queries on source tables

If on different instances or servers (can also work if on same instance though):

- SSIS Package to identify changes and push to DB2 (bonus can work with change data capture)
- Merge Replication to synchronize changes
- AlwaysOn Availability Groups to synchronize entire dbs
- Microsoft Sync Framework

Knowing nothing about your preferences or comfort levels, I would probably start with Merge Replication - can be a bit tricky and tedious to setup, but performs very well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Both of you. I'm not too familiar with merge replication, so I will have to look into that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a trigger in DB1 and  dblinks in between DB1 and DB2. So you can natively invoke trigger within DB1 and transfer data directly to DB2.